# Shopify API Paginate Through Orders to Get Accurate Count

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

In Shopify ORDERS API, I use

```
/admin/api/2021-01/orders/count.json
```

In order to get the orders count, so I wanted to get all the orders. And by followign the REST API Documentation, I used two endpoints to do this.

`/admin/api/2021-01/orders.json?status=any`

`/admin/api/2021-01/orders.json?limit=250&status=any; rel=next`

First I would request the orders using the first endpoint where I get up to 50 orders/items in a list.

Then by using the counter as a limit, lets say I have 550 orders that I got from the response of `orders/count.json`

I do:

```
accumulated = []
iter = 0
while True:
    if len(accumulated) > count:
        break
    if iter != 1:
        url = #user first url
    else:
        url = $use second url that has next

    items = #make a request here for that url and save each order item
    accumulated+=items #this saves each list to the accumulated list so we know that we hit the count
```

But for some reason im only getting a fraction of the count. Lets say out of 550 on count, I only get 350 that are not duplicates of each other. Im thinking that maybe the second url, only requests the second page and doesnt proceed to the third page. Hence I was doing

```
first iteration = first page
second iteration = second page
third iteration = second page
```

all those gets into the accumulated list and stops the loop because of the condition that when accumulated exceeds count the loop will stop.

How can I make it so when I request ORDERS Endpoint in shopify. I go from the next pages properly?

I tried following shopify's [tutorial in making paginated requests](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/make-paginated-requests-to-rest-admin-api), but its unclear for me. on how to use it. THeres this `page_info` variable thats hard to me to understand where to find it and how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy! In Shopify REST api you can get max 250 orders per api call and if there are more orders you get `LINK` from header which contain URL for your next page request like
[Here you can see I have LINK variable in my response headers you just need to get this LINK and check for rel='next' flag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg6XS.png)

But keep in mind when you hit the new URL and still you have more orders to fetch then the Header sent LINK with two URL 1 for Previous and 1 for the next.

run this snippet to get LINK from headers

```
var flag = false;
var next_url = order.headers.link;
if(next_url){
  flag = true
  next_url = next_url.replace("<","");
  next_url = next_url.replace(">", "");
  var next_url_array = next_url.split('; ');
  var link_counter_start = next_url_array[0].indexOf("page_info=")+10;
  var link_counter_length = (next_url_array[0].length);
  var next_cursor="";
  var link_counter;
  for(link_counter=link_counter_start; link_counter<link_counter_length; link_counter++){
    next_cursor+=(next_url_array[0][link_counter])
  }
}
```

for the very first api But if you have more then two pages use the following code to seprate next link from previos and next flag

```
next_url = order.headers.link;
      var next_url_array,
       link_counter_start, link_counter_length,
        link_counter;
      if(next_url.includes(',')){
        next_url = next_url.split(',');
        next_url = next_url[1];
      }
  
  next_url = next_url.replace("<","");
  next_url = next_url.replace(">", "");
  next_url_array = next_url.split('; ');
  link_counter_start = next_url_array[0].indexOf("page_info=")+10;
  link_counter_length = (next_url_array[0].length);
  next_cursor="";
  for(link_counter=link_counter_start; link_counter<link_counter_length; link_counter++){
    next_cursor+=(next_url_array[0][link_counter])
  }
  if(next_url_array[1] != 'rel="next"'){
    flag = false;
  }
```